# How to Copy Object With a Custom Content Type?

Tags: content-type, copy-and-paste

In SharePoint I have created a custom content type at the root site level. It's a "described folder", inheriting from the folder type and adding an extra column that can hold a textual description. I then created a document library within this site, and some of the sub-sub-folders are "described folder" objects. I want to copy some "described folders" from one part of the document library to a different part. It is all within the same document library, so the custom content type is defined in both source and destination folders.

If I browse the folder structure with Windows Explorer, I can move the "described folders", and they will retain their custom metadata (the fact that they are a custom type as well as the description that is associated to them). However, if I copy the "described folders", they will lose the extra metadata and will become a regular "folder" content type in the destination folder, losing the description that was associated to it. I don't see any way to copy-paste within the SharePoint web interface. Is it possible to copy custom content type objects within a document library while retaining the custom information associated?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there are only 2 options how to move folders retaining custom metadata:

1. windows explorer
2. powershell

Why is windows explorer solution not good enough?

Comment: The problem with Windows Explorer: "However, if I copy the "described folders", they will lose the extra metadata and will become a regular "folder" content type in the destination folder, losing the description that was associated to it."